# Django disable a link if list returns empty

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I don't want to display a link if the list returns empty.

**template.html**

```
{% for item in cart %}
<h1>{{ item.product.product_title }}</h1>
<a href="{% url 'products:remove_from_cart' item.product.id %}">Remove item</a>
{% empty %}
<p>No items in cart</p>
{% endfor %}
{% if item is not None %}
<p>
<a href="{% url 'products:checkout' %}">Checkout</a>
</p>
{% endif %}
```

**views.py**

```
def cartview(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, active=True)
    orders = ProductOrder.objects.filter(cart=cart)
    #total = 0
    count = 0
    for order in orders:)
        count += order.quantity
    context = {
        'cart': orders,
        'count': count,
    }
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)
else:
    return redirect('index:index')
```

I want to hide checkout link if the cart list is empty. putting it in the for loop would make the link appear many times. I want to display checkout button only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `'item'` check for `'cart'` in the template.

```
{% if cart %}
<p>
<a href="{% url 'products:checkout' %}">Checkout</a>
</p>
{% endif %}
```